# Customize WooCommerce Order Details Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need help with something that I cant find any information online.

I want to change a label in WooCommerce custom page as shown in the example.

I customized checkout so I dont need address info. I would only require to show the name in that section.

[image]

What hooks should I use?

I appreciate your time and help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my [tutorial on customizing checkout fields](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/woocommerce-customize-checkout-fields/) here's an example of how to display data on that panel:

```
// display the extra data in the order admin panel
function kia_display_order_data_in_admin( $order ){  ?>
    <div class="order_data_column">
        <h4><?php _e( 'Extra Details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h4>
        <?php 
            echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'Some field' ) . ':</strong>' . get_post_meta( $order->id, '_some_field', true ) . '</p>';
            echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'Another field' ) . ':</strong>' . get_post_meta( $order->id, '_another_field', true ) . '</p>'; ?>
    </div>
<?php }
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'kia_display_order_data_in_admin' );
```

Comment: Ok if i add the field i can show the name, but how do i hide adress details? We are not using that panel.

Comment: It does not appear possible to remove that from WooCommerce's admin without removing the *entire* metabox and re-supplying your own, which you'd then be responsible for maintaining as WooCommerce is updated. The best alternative would then be to simply hide it via CSS.